# AnimationDrawable from play to stop icon on FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button, animationdrawable

I have a web radio player app that haves a FloatingActionButton to play and stop the reproduction. When the player is not playing, the icon is a play, when it is playing, the icon is a stop.
Some days ago I saw an animation that could be very good to my app, where a play icon morphs in a stop icon, something like [this](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/delightful-details.html).
I've been searching for a tutorial or lib to help me with this but unsuccessfully.
Im using [this FAB](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton).
**Any help is welcome. Thaks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this [library](https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat) will help you. It already contains such animation and also provides backward compatibility on devices with SDK level >= 14

Comment: I guess is exactly what i need.
I cannot test now but i'll as soon as possible.
Very thanks.